Terraform provider alias dependency is not being properly validated
Setup:
I'm currently developing a terraform module which requires two providers. One default azurerm one and one aliased azurerm provider. The setup in the module currently looks like:
versions.tf:
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">= 3.0"

      # azurerm alias used for a certain piece of data
      configuration_aliases = [azurerm.alias_name]
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 1.1.0, < 2.0.0"
}

This provider alias is used to get a single data resource in the module. Something like:
main.tf:
data "azurerm_function_app" "alias-provider-resource" {
  provider = azurerm.alias_name
  name     = var.function_app_name
  # ...
}

All the other resources in the module use the default provider azurerm. The idea is then that you call this module like so:
module "our-module-name" {
  source  = "source.url.com/our-module"
  version = "1.0.0"

  providers = {
    azurerm.alias_name = azurerm.some_alias
  }
}

Issue:
When validating this setup we use this image and run gitlab-terraform init followed by gitlab-terraform validate. The issue is that this validation initializes the required providers, but does not initialize the required configuration alias. This results in the validation stage failing with:
│ Error: Provider configuration not present
│ 
│ To work with data.azurerm_function_app.alias-provider-resource its
│ original provider configuration at
│ provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm"].alias_name is
│ required, but it has been removed. This occurs when a provider
│ configuration is removed while objects created by that provider still exist
│ in the state. Re-add the provider configuration to destroy
│ data.azurerm_function_app.alias-provider-resource, after which you
│ can remove the provider configuration again.

We've currently solved this issue by creating the provider in the versions.tf file in the module:
terraform {
  # ...
}

provider "azurerm" {
  alias = "alias_name"
  features {}
}

But this will cause the aliased provider to inherit the ARM_ environment configuration. Is there any way to avoid declaring the provider in the module and still validate?

Do you have the azurerm.some_alias definition in the root module?

@MarkoE yes, the definition of the alias is made in the root module. Issue is validating the child module
